# Permutation and combination 4 digits number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know how to compute the number four-digits strings: $10^4$, but I'm stuck on how to qualify this with the condition that at least two digits are different. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Find the number of 4 digit numbers in which all digits are the same, and subtract this from the total number of 4 digit numbers.

Let me know how you progress with the hint above; feel free to leave a comment/question  below this answer.

Comment: Have a nice and colorful dream. :-)